# Problems with visible image change in Gridview while scrollings

Tags: android, gridview, android-cursoradapter, universal-image-loader

I have a Gridview that loads the data correctly and is smooth. The problem that I am running into is that when the user scrolls through the Gridview with any pace they can see the images change in the UI. The images ultimately end up in the right spot but it just isn't very aesthetically for the user. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong and what I could do to get a clean scroll. It might be important to note I am using the Universal Image Loader and a Cursor Loader. My adapter code is posted below.

```
class VideoAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
Context context; 
private static final String TAG = "Checking Database";
ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
public VideoAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    this.context = context;

    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
    .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context))
    .build();

    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions =
            new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheOnDisc()
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) 
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    Log.i(TAG, "at thconstructore end of the the ");
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    int videoid = cursor.getColumnIndex(GridviewData.ROWID);
    int videopath = cursor.getColumnIndex(GridviewData.VIDEOFILEPATH);
    String rowid = cursor.getString(videoid);
    String filepath = cursor.getString(videopath);
            //This background thread downloads/looks for the bitmap and sets it to the  view
    BitmapDownloader bitdl = new BitmapDownloader(rowid, filepath,    holder.imageview);
    bitdl.execute();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View eachgrid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eachgrid, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.imageview = (ImageView) eachgrid
            .findViewById(R.id.Imageview1);
    eachgrid.setTag(holder);
    return eachgrid;        
}
```

Thanks for your help.